# MS Excel 2016 Power Pivot TOTALYTD does NOT take cumulative

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

**Software:** MS Excel 2016 Power Pivot

TOTALYTD acts as sum for each time period rather than a cumulative.

I have a separate Calendar table in Power Pivot and I created relationship with my main table.

Here is the formula

```
YTD_Matches:=TOTALYTD(sum(Complete_Detailed_Incidents[Matches]),'Calendar'[Date])
```

When I create Pivot, below is what it looks like.  How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like?  A "Matches" and a "Dates" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one year in your model, you will need to put year on rows also.

Otherwise the issue is something in your model (something you have not shown).

I was able to create a cumulative year to date using your numbers in an Excel 2016 workbook which you can download from [this link.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bozmq2oqub0lau/ForRhonda.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I think Rhonda means that February should contain January numbers, etc.

Comment: N8: Have you downloaded the example? If so, do you think Rhonda is asking for different results?

Comment: @P3Tom This answers my question perfectly. Original problem was, I got Month from `Complete_Detailed_Incidents` rather than `Calendar`, i.e. Date table. Thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't, my policy is not to download attachments.  But I'm glad it was resolved to everyone's satisfaction.